# Changing Results to be presented in a 'Tree view' from a 'Combo box'

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment when a user logs in, a Stored Procedure will run to search a table and bring back a `TaskId`, which will be displayed in a drop down list.

```
private void Refresh()
{

        var _AuditUserId = _loggedInUser;
        cAuditUserEntity user = _AuditUserId as cAuditUserEntity;

        int userid = user.AuditUserId;

        _tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid).ToList();

        var result = (from cAuditTasksEntity tasks in _tasks
                      select tasks.TaskId).ToList();

        cmbToDoList.ItemsSource = result;

}
```

If I was going to go about changing the drop down list to a tree view and then separate the `TaskIds` by different sections of that tree View how would I go about doing this? Also, would it be an easy thing to get though, as I am new to WPF and coding in general.

Comment: What is wrong with setting it as the TreeView Itemssource?

Comment: @DaveRook When I set it as the ItemSource, how would I go about setting different tasks in different Items in the 'Tree View'

Comment: @DaveRook Ahh ok, Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: Your original post doesn't explain anything about different tasks and different items? I can see you want to bring back a list of TaskID's but, what are the Items? Or do you mean you want to be able to expand each ID to see any children

Comment: @DaveRook Well, My SQL table Has `TaskId` `TransactionId` `Date` and other things .. `TransactionId` links to another table which displays `TransactionId` `Pot` and other things .. The Tree view has Items with the different Pots. I have the `TasksIds` already in a Combo Box I just need to look at the pot the `TasksId` is in and put it into the correct Item in the Tree View.

Comment: Add a treeview to your XAML and update code to `var result = (from cAuditTasksEntity tasks in _tasks select tasks).ToList(); this.MyTreeView.ItemsSource = result;` and just try it! Then, report back with what it does wrong as I'm still struggling to fully understand the issue here (sorry)