# Exception for finding the SelectedItem in a Treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

At the moment I have method I created so that when you click anything in the Treeview, the method will activate.

```
private void MyTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
        cAuditTasksEntity task = new cAuditTasksEntity();

        cAuditTasksEntity entityTask = MyTreeView.SelectedItem as cAuditTasksEntity;
}
```

[image]

This is my To-Do-list, When they select something from anything in the list of `_Pot` which on the picture includes `Acceptance Pot 1` `Acceptance Pot 2`, I need it to return that `SelectedItem`.

With that `SelectedItem` in a variable I can get the `PolicyNumber` and search the database for that `Task`(the `SelectedItems`) details.

EDIT:

I have added this code:

`var Info = MyTreeView.SelectedItem;`

I know it will do any `SelectedItem` in the TreeView but I can add an `IF` statement around it, this reads the `Date & PolicyNumber` from the picture I shown with that how can I get the `PolicyNumber` and find the `TransactionType` that matches that `Policynumber`.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @gleng How can I find the `SelectedItem` of just the ones under the list `_Pot` which includes on this picture `Acceptance Pot 1`

Comment: Hmm... starting to feel like you might be trying to get Stack Overflow to do all the programming for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655466/selecteditem-method-in-treeview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639134/how-to-put-a-treeviewitem-into-a-generated-treeviewitem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636610/converting-a-list-into-treeviewitems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632547/changing-results-to-be-presented-in-a-tree-view-from-a-combo-box

Comment: @JDB Wow... I should pay more attention to these things.

Comment: @JDB I am an Apprentice Software Developer, I'm learning and if you read the questions and comments, they have become useful to other people and also on the comments I have been told to ask another question with my point. I am learning, helping other people learn and helping the website to grow, can you please explain the problem?

Comment: @user3110814 - Your questions are generally well asked, but the primary issue I see here is that you don't seem to be taking the time to research these questions on your own (see [ask]). This results in a lot of duplicate and somewhat trivial questions. Also, as a student, it's less important to get the work done and more important to learn how to think through the problem. Asking these kinds of questions on SO is cheating yourself out of an education (and the glory of figuring it out on your own).

Comment: @JDB Thank you for your feedback, I will take what you said on-board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a `SelectedItem` property on your view model. You can then bind your `SelectedItem` to this property in xaml:

```
<... SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem} />
```

You can then access this within the method you have defined.